# Notifications review optimization

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

I'm just curious about review feature on Ask Ubuntu. For example when you finish 20 suggested edits then it tells you to come back in 5-8 hours etc. but still keep pushing notifications on available suggested edits review though if you click on it replies please come back later... so on.

Wouldn't it be better functionality if it block notifications for that period of time on suggested edits or even more better switch notification pushes for example to "Low Quality Posts" for that period of time?

Comment: Yeah, that would be really nice! **:-)** Something to be asked at http://meta.stackexchange.com with tag "feature-request"...

Comment: @Fabby just posted it there too ;)

Comment: @JoKeR can I have the link to upvote there? :)

Comment: @Tim it's here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257892/notifications-review-optimization

Comment: More than blocking them I'd rather not show them for the "maxed out" queues, you cannot be aware of this but once you can review say tag wiki edits those adds up to the notifications number, so yeah, I agree on not counting "maxed out" queues ;)